# Percentage in Matrix Table

Tags: matrix, dax, percentage, measure

I am a new user of Power BI and I am having trouble displaying the percentage completion in a matrix visual. I used a *template to bring* in the numbers from the source, but the percentage is showing as either zero or one. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Fields in dataset: Account Name

Row group: Status (MEC on Time / Delayed)

Column group: Months

Details: Counts of Account Name

Thank you!